# How to get unbuffered response from thin server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin, actioncontroller

I am using ActionController::Live to stream a long response in parts, but of course breaking up the response is pointless when the server buffers the response until everything is done anyway. When thin is my rails server, it insists on buffering, contrary to the assurances of Aaron Patterson (http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html) and Ryan Bates (http://railscasts.com/episodes/401-actioncontroller-live?view=asciicast) that thin is a viable server for Live. There must be a way to make it work but I'm going nuts trying to figure it out. My server configuration is default all the way, both in development and on heroku. When I switch over to puma, all is well, but I'd rather not open a can of worms by switching servers. Is there some config option required? Some strange interaction with another gem that makes thin buffer its response? Could these guys really be wrong?

To see for yourself, do 'curl -i http:strong-galaxy-5765-74.herokuapp.com/stream/buffer_test' . It's the classic sleep-between-items method of checking for buffering, sleeping 5 seconds per line, 10 seconds total. It's running the default thin server on heroku.

I apologize for asking such a generic question, but I really don't know how to get to more information.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Thin is definitely buffering even when running locally.